# GEKKO multiple variables deep learning function approximation

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to approximate one function and then use it in the dynamic GEKKO simulation. I could not find any information on how to do this with multiple variables (such as a,b,d function parameters). Here is the example of the code:

```
from gekko import brain
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b = brain.Brain(remote = False)
b.input_layer(1)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.layer(tanh=5)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.output_layer(1)

x = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
a = np.linspace(0,1,10)
b = np.linspace(0,0.5,10)
d = np.linspace(-1,0,10)

def function(x,a,b,d):
    y = 0.0001*x + a*b*x + d
    return y

b.learn(x,function(x)) # Not sure here how to implement, does not allow multiple variables in x
xp = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
yp = b.think(xp)
plt.figure()
# plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(xp,yp[0],'r-')
plt.show()
```

Does anybody know how can I train the model for this?

Also is there any method to save the model so that I dont need to train it every time, and I would simply insert it into the dynamic simulation (GEKKO IMODE 4 or 7).

Finally I am struggling to get a certain value after training the model. I have to specify x = np.linspace(0,0.000001,100) (the same form of x as for training) to get y at point x = 0. Is there any simpler method just to write y = b.think(0) and get one value at x = 0? Or y = b.think(0,0.1,...,...) with multiple variables .

I would really appreciate to get an answer for at least of some questions :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `scikit-learn` to train a [neural network](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/MultilayerPerceptronNeuralNetwork), [support vector regressor](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/SupportVectorRegressor), or [gaussian process regression](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/GaussianProcessRegression) and then import it into Gekko. The latest version `v1.0.5` supports import from `scikit-learn` and `gpflow` packages. It is currently on [test.pypi.org](https://test.pypi.org/project/gekko/) and should be released to `pypi.org` by August 2022. There are [examples in the documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html).

For the [gekko brain module](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brain.html), below is an example of training and prediction adapted from the [Machine Learning course](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/MultilayerPerceptronNeuralNetwork). That page also has a `scikit-learn` and `keras/tensorflow` example.

[image: nn result]

```py
from gekko import brain
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# set random seed
np.random.seed(0)

# generate training data
n = 20 # samples
x = np.random.rand(n)*2 # between 0 and 2
a = np.random.rand(n)   # between 0 and 1
c = np.random.rand(n)*0.5 # between 0 and 0.5
d = np.random.rand(n)*-1  # between 0 and -1
def function(x,a,c,d):
    y = 0.0001*x + a*c*x + d
    return y
z = function(x,a,c,d)

# consolidate inputs
inputs = np.vstack((x,a,c,d))
output = z

b = brain.Brain(remote = False)
b.input_layer(4)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.layer(tanh=5)
b.layer(linear=2)
b.output_layer(1)
# train
b.learn(inputs,output)      

# validate with new numbers
x = np.random.rand(n)*2 # between 0 and 2
a = np.random.rand(n)   # between 0 and 1
c = np.random.rand(n)*0.5 # between 0 and 0.5
d = np.random.rand(n)*-1  # between 0 and -1
z = function(x,a,c,d)
inputs = np.vstack((x,a,c,d))
output = z

output_pred = b.think(inputs)  

plt.figure()
plt.plot(output,output_pred[0],'ro')
plt.plot([-1,1],[-1,1],'k-')
plt.show()
```

For neural network models, it is important to [scale the data](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/ScaleData) with either a MinMax scalar or else a Standard scalar.